# Is there a way to enable Quiet Hours without Cortana?

Tags: 8.1, cortana, quiet-hours

I downloaded the dev preview of WP 8.1 and temporarily set my region to US in order to test Cortana. During my testing, I could configure the so-called *quiet hours* feature.

After I've tested Cortana to my heart's content, I set my region back to what it originally was. The reason for that has to do with the store, the different regions' different currencies and the fact that I use pre-paid cards to buy stuff.

Now that Cortana's (temporarily) gone from my phone, I noticed I still get notifications in the middle of the night (from 2 AM to 6 AM); so obviously the *quiet hours* feature didn't work.

Is there a way to enable that feature without enabling Cortana, or am I forced to set my region to US until Cortana is available in my region, if I want to sleep well at night without toggling all notifications every time I go to bed or wake up?

Comment: Vote is here: https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5761710-let-us-use-quiet-hours-now-outside-the-us-independ

Comment: And here: http://cortana.uservoice.com/forums/249009-general-cortana-feedback/suggestions/5875033-decouple-features-like-quiet-hours-from-cortana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, quiet hours is a Cortana feature. When I have her enabled, there is a "quiet hours" option in my settings menu. That redirects me to Cortana's quiet hours settings menu. This leads me to believe she must be enabled.

Here's quiet hours in my settings menu
[image: Settings]

Look at the top of the screen, it says Cortana.
[image: Cortana]

Comment: Very bad MS. So bad.

Comment: @AlexanderLogger Not really. If Quiet Hours is managed by Cortana, why should it work when Cortana is disabled? It's like berating Apple because you can't use your iPhone while it's turned off.

Comment: @Shawn iPhone has integrated Quiet Hours and it works without enabled Siri. Hence why on Earth Windows Phone should has Cortana enabled to perform such a simple offline feature as Quiet Hours.

Comment: @AlexanderLogger I get what you mean, but what I'm saying is that iPhone's Quiet Hours (or DND, or whatever it's called) is not integrated into Siri-- leastways not as deeply as WP Quiet Hours is integrated into Cortana. And since it's part of Cortana, you turn it off when you turn Cortana off.

Comment: @Shawn yes, I'm talking about a big design mistake that QH is a part of the Cortana, and not a part of a core system.

Comment: @AlexanderLogger "A big design mistake"... Not really.

Answer (score -1):

WP8.1 - You can add Quiet Hours as one of your four Quick Actions. Go to Settings | Notifications, tap one box and assign it to Quiet Hours. When you slide down your Notifications it will be available as a toggle. Alas, no Cortana voice command yet.

Comment: You can add the toggle, yes, but if you actually try to use it, you'll be prompted to enable Cortana. So this doesn't actually solve the problem.